# Saving Docker container state on Windows

Tags: windows, docker

I create a docker container using

```
docker-machine.exe create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-memory 2048 default
```

and I logged into the `bash` using

```
docker run -ti ubuntu /bin/bash
```

and I got something like `root@ae78cd536ddf:/#` where I did a couple of `apt-get install`s.

Then, I exited from the bash and when I again logged back in I could not find what I had installed. I wanted to do a `docker commit`, but I somehow can't figure where my installed stuff is?

**UPDATE**

Based on the answers I tried creating an image of the container. I have compiled all commands in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/apanimesh061/7e5291add890560f08fef2e813e67dbc).

Answer (score 2):

With `docker run`, you create a container from the `ubuntu` image. The container has the name `ae78cd536ddf` (in your case). You can inspect images and containers with `docker ps -a` and `docker images` respectively.

Each time you run `docker run`, a new container is created. When using `docker run --name Somename`, you force the container to be named `Somename` which prevents you from creating another container with the same name.

Images are immutable which means you can not change them. So when you modify something in the running container, the image stays the same and this you can create more containers from the same image.

So after you stopped a container (`docker stop`, exit the containerized bash or just reboot), you can run `docker start ae78cd536ddf` to restart it. But it will be running in background and you won't have a bash (check `docker ps` to see it's running). Now you just need a bash: `docker exec -it ae78cd536ddf /bin/bash` will execute a bash in the container you started before.

---

Just a note about creating images. You might want to install the software you always need (I personally love vim, htop, ...) and then `docker commit` the container. This will create a new image which you can see in `docker images`. Now you can run containers from this image by replacing `ubuntu` with your image name.

To get more reproducable builds (when using a CI for example), you can create a [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) and run `docker build`.

Answer (score 1):

Every `docker run` command creates a new container. The id in the hostname of the bash shell is the container ID. You can commit that.

To see all containers (including stopped containers), do `docker ps -a`.